# How do I load images/content from the Public folder into a dynamic routed page in NextJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How do I load an image from the Public folder into a dynamic route in NextJs?

In the docs I saw nothing about this... It is stated that we can add content from the Public file - for example `<img src="/Content/image.jpg" alt="some alt" />`. Yet, if I am in a dynamic routed page, for example `/pages/post/[id].js` The solution presented in Next's docs does not work, nothing is loaded.

How is this tackled, best practices, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All assets that are in the `public` folder will be available like any resource on the internet.

It is probably a matter of path, if you serving your app from `example.com`, and your images has `/Content/image.jpg` (pay attention to the first slash, this tells to the browser to start at the **root**) in this case, the **absolute** path is relative to the domain and **not** to the path that the page is served at.

This means that there is no affect of dynamic routes on the images path.

Just make sure that your `public` folder has `Content` (make sure that the folder starts with capital `C`) folder.

Comment: It worked after a while when I restarted the local server. I honestly don't know why this error was happening. Thanks for replying here anyway =)